# Magento 2 : installation stuck at 67%

Tags: magento2, installation

Magento 2 Installation stuck at 67% every time I tried. The question has been asked before but the solutions offered for those posts didn't help.

`memory_limit = 2048M` on both `php.ini` & `user.ini`
`max_execution_time = 360`

Any one knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install your Magento via command line:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands.html
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

For example:

> php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
>   --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento \
>   --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
>   --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
>   --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
>   --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --cleanup-database \
>   --sales-order-increment-prefix="ORD$" --session-save=db --use-rewrites=1